# Microsoft SQL Unions with parent and Child Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0SXN.png)I am hoping someone can lead me in the right direction. I am working with Microsoft SQL and I need to return a parent row, with child rows underneath that but I need to do this for everyone in the table. I have tried a cursor and they will give me the desired results but it returns each one in its on separate result window. On top of that I need to be able to Union other data to the Parent and Child. When all said and done all data will be returned within one SQL query set.

```
Select user_name from test (This is a header)
Union All
Select Parent_name, Parent_DOB, Parent_Phone from Parents
```

Now I want to find any children that belong to the parent above and have them listed underneath the parent each in their own row.

Then repeat the parent-child combo for every parent in the table.

Then after all parents and children have been listed I need to union some footers

Union All
Select blah blah from blah (this is the footer)

Here is the code :

```
Declare @SequentialRun varchar(5)
set @SequentialRun = 19999
Declare @PayID varchar(10)
Declare @PTDBWGross as nvarchar(50)
Declare @PTDMOGross as nvarchar(50)
set @PayID = '19361*BW';     -- Need to find a better way to do this
Declare @PayMOID varchar(10)
set @PayMOID = '19373*MO';     -- Need to find a better way to do this
    set @PTDBWGross = (
SELECT SUM(PTD_GROSS)  -
(Select sum(PTD_BD_EMPLYE_CALC_AMTS) 
FROM PTD WHERE PTD_BD_CODES IN ('D1EE','H1EC','R3%M','V1EC')
AND Left(PAYTODAT_ID,8) = @PayID) FROM PAYTODAT
WHERE Left(PAYTODAT_ID,8) = @PayID

); -- Current Taxable Wages

        set @PTDMOGross = (
SELECT SUM(PTD_GROSS)  -
(Select sum(PTD_BD_EMPLYE_CALC_AMTS) 
FROM PTDBNDED WHERE PTD_BD_CODES IN ('D1EE','H1EC','R3%M','V1EC')
AND Left(PAYTODAT_ID,8) = @PayMOID) FROM PAYTODAT
WHERE Left(PAYTODAT_ID,8) = @PaymoID); -- Current Taxable Wages


WITH Xheader AS
(
Select 'X' --Record Identifier plus blank
+' '+
+ 'T3.03' -- File format version
+'I' -- Interim
+'2021' -- year for tax data
+'1' -- quarter for tax data
+ replace(replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),112),'/',''),'-','') --Creation Date
+ replace(replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),8),':',''),'-','') -- Creation Time
+ CAST('Some University' as CHAR(50))      --Extract Program Information    
+space(10)
+' 1'
+space(70)
+ CAST('System' as CHAR(25))
+ CAST('5.16' as CHAR(25))  
+'InterfaceVersio'
+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) as TaxData,'' AS SPC,'' AS SPC1,''AS SPC2,''AS SPC3,''AS SPC4,''AS SPC5,''AS SPC6,''AS SPC7,''AS SPC8,''AS SPC9,''AS SPC10,''AS SPC11,''AS SPC12
),


HHEADER AS
(
Select 'H' --Record Identifier plus blank
+ ' ' -- File format version
+ CAST('2NI' as CHAR(14))
+' '
+CAST('Some University' as CHAR(50))
+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) AS HHEADER,'' AS SPC,'' AS SPC1,''AS SPC2,''AS SPC3,''AS SPC4,''AS SPC5,''AS SPC6,''AS SPC7,''AS SPC8,''AS SPC9,''AS SPC10,''AS SPC11,''AS SPC12
),

RecordE as 
(
Select 'E' AS RECORDID
,SPACE(7) AS SPACES7
,P.ID AS ID
, ISNULL(REPLACE(SSN,'-',''),SPACE(9)) AS SSN
,CAST(P.FIRST_NAME AS VARCHAR(17)) AS FIRST_NAME
,ISNULL(LEFT(P.MIDDLE_NAME,1),' ') AS MIDDLE_NAME
,SPACE(16) AS SPACES16
,P.LAST_NAME AS LAST_NAME
,ADDRESS AS ADDRESS
,ISNULL(ADDRESS2,SPACE(30)) AS ADDRESS2
,ISNULL(PV.CITY,SPACE(30)) AS CITY
,ISNULL(PV.STATE,SPACE(2)) AS STATE
,ISNULL(REPLACE(PV.ZIP,'-',''),SPACE(9)) AS ZIP
,SPACE(96) 
+CHAR(13)
+CHAR(10) AS SPACES96ANDCRLF
from TEST P
INNER JOIN TEST2 PV ON PV.ID = P.ID
WHERE P.LAST_NAME IS NOT NULL AND SSN IS NOT NULL

-----I need the information below to be returned underneath each person above that is returned------------------

--(SELECT ISNULL(dbo.PadLeft(SUM(PTD_EMPLYE_TAX_AMTS),16), dbo.PadLeft(0,16)) 
--,'' AS SPC,'' AS SPC1,''AS SPC2,''AS SPC3,''AS SPC4,''AS SPC5,''AS SPC6,''AS SPC7,''AS SPC8,''AS SPC9,''AS SPC10,''AS SPC11,''AS SPC12
--FROM [TAXES] PTAX where PTAX.PTD_TAX_CODES = 'CC02' AND Left(PTAX.PAYTODAT_ID,8) = '19373*MO')

--person
--person data
--person
--person data

) 

Select * from Xheader
Union ALL
Select * from HHEADER
Union ALL
Select * from RecordE
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.  Also note that a SQL returns returns a result set with all rows having the *same* columns.  Your pseud-code is not in this format.

Comment: In  a UNION you need the same number of columns, you can't UNION a single-field result with a 3-field result. Think about what you actually want the output table to look like. Both parts of the UNION need to fit that table structure.

Comment: The rows returned by a query have no particular order - do not assume otherwise. If you want a particular order, an ORDER BY clause is required to enforce it.

Comment: SQL queries don't have headers. You can't have different columns in a UNION's queries

Comment: I have created other files like this in the past. Created Headers and Footers using CTE, then union on other data. I just make sure that each CTE has the same amount of data.

Comment: Add desired results and code so far

Comment: If you've done this before, then you either have forgotten how to do it or you were using a very different technique. As the others have explained, UNION requires all resultsets to have the same number of columns and the datatypes of those columns must be the same (or implicitly convertible). Perhaps your prior technique was based on creating one giant string column for your detail "lines" by concatenating all the columns in that query together. Seems this is your path with the use of  SPACE functions in cte named RecordE but you left out the concatenation.